# Why do I need FromBody Attribute when expecting data in POST body

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-mvc

I can send my data to the server but ONLY when I use the FromBody-Attribute.

Why is the json data not automatically read from the Body using a Post?

**Backend web api**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]CreateSchoolyearRequestDTO dto)
{

}
```

**Frontend angularjs**

```
this.createSchoolyear = function (schoolyear) {
  var path = "/api/schoolyears";
  return $http({
      url: path,
      method: "POST",
      data:  schoolyear,
      contentType: "application/json"
  }).then(function (response) {
      return response;
  });
};
```

Comment: Because you are sending POST data as payload (in POST body)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just because something is a POST request, there is no clear rule how arguments are being transferred. A POST request can still contain query parameters encoded in the URL. A method parameter is expected to be a query parameter for “simple” types (strings, ints, etc.).

Complex types are usually expected to be POST form objects. The standard ASP.NET POST request is a form submit, e.g. when logging in. The parameters in those request are usually encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, basically a string of key/value pairs. For complex parameter types, e.g. form view model objects, this is assumed the default.

For all other non-default situations, you need to be explicit where a method parameter comes from, how it is being transferred in the request. For that purpose, there are a number of different attributes:

- `FromBodyAttribute` – For parameters that come from the request body
- `FromFormAttribute` – For parameters that come from a single form data field
- `FromHeaderAttribute` – For parameters that come from a HTTP header field
- `FromQueryAttribute` – For parameters that come from a query argument encoded in the URL
- `FromRouteAttribute` – For parameters that come from the route data
- `FromServicesAttribute` – For parameters for which services should be injected at method-level

Comment: totally forgot that Post is reading too from Url. Then FromBody makes sense!

Comment: I think this is how Web API worked, but now web api and MVC are merges this is a breaking change with ASP.NET Core. My previous Web API project worked as expected, now I'm having to put [FromBody] everywhere. `[FromBody]` forced JSON.net to be used

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Yes, ASP.NET Core is deliberately incompatible to classic ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI. Thus, you are expected to have breaking changes. – For API controllers, you will be able to use the `[ApiController]` attribute starting with ASP.NET Core 2.1 to enable an inferred `FromBody` model binding (along with [a few other conventions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/#mvc)), so you won’t need the attribute on every action anymore.

Comment: I didn't know about the `[ApiController]`attribute. - Is there any documentation outlining all the breaking changes?

Comment: The `ApiController` attribute is not yet there but coming in the next release. – Breaking changes between ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core? No, there is no documentation or anything. You should consider ASP.NET Core as a completely different framework which just feels similar in *some* parts.