# Json.Net Deserialization In DotNet Core Web Api

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core, json-deserialization, asp.net-core-webapi

**TLDR;** Can not parse querystring data to object model using Json.net deserializer.

**Long version:**
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json's DefaultContractResolver for Json serializer in dotnet core 2.0;

```
var mvc = services.AddMvc();
mvc.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
});
```

In web api controller, i'm using a model;

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public Core.Data.Models.Request.DataSourceRequestModel Get(Core.Data.Models.Request.DataSourceRequestModel req)
    {
        return req;
    }
}
```

And DataSourceRequestModel is;

```
public sealed class DataSourceRequestModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
    public int Start { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "limit")]
    public int Limit { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "filter")]
    public ICollection<DataSourceRequestFilterModel> Filters { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sort")]
    public ICollection<DataSourceRequestSortModel> Sorts { get; set; }

    public DataSourceRequestModel()
    {
        Limit = 25;
    }
}
public class DataSourceRequestFilterModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class DataSourceRequestSortModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property")]
    public string Property { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "direction")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling controller with this query;
http://localhost:9417/api/values/?_dc=1505751693766&page=1&start=99&limit=163&filter=%5B%7B%22Property%22%3A%22Code%22%2C%22Value%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Operator%22%3A%22eq%22%7D%2C%7B%22property%22%3A%22Name%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%5Cu00fccretli%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22eq%22%7D%5D

Basically, i'm sending this value as querystring;

```
_dc:1505755748815
page:1
start:99
limit:163
sort:[{"property":"Name","direction":"ASC"}]
filter:[{"property":"Code","value":"","operator":"eq"},{"property":"Name","value":"Ucretli","operator":"eq"}]
```

As a result, i'm getting this;

```
{
    "start": 99,
    "limit": 163,
    "filter": null,
    "sort": null
}
```

Json.net deserializer could not parse filter and sort properties, just simply ignoring them. Even if i change property names, this time it does not return null values but again, i'm getting empty array.

Any ideas which causes that problem?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1**: In DataSourceRequestModel, i've both tried List and DataSourceRequestFilterModel[] array changes and still no success.

**Edit 2**: For further references, i'm going to share the solution i've found. As [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286088/json-net-deserialization-in-dotnet-core-web-api#comment79537518_46286088)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286088/json-net-deserialization-in-dotnet-core-web-api#comment79537447_46286088) has mentioned here below, dotnet core does not use Json.Net for complex model binding so the properties in model stays null. So you have to create and use your own custom model binders, detailed here;
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1368/aspnet-core-mvc-custom-model-binding

Thanks again to everyone who has involved.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Have you tried changing the `ICollection` to `List` or using an array? If you "need" an `ICollection`, then try using an intermediate object and transfer the data?

Comment: Yes, i've tried both List and array definition and still no success.

Comment: You seem to be expecting that Json.NET will get used for binding complex types to url encoded values.  This appears not to be the case; [`ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs) doesn't seem to use Json.NET at all and binds via reflection.

Comment: If you want to use Json.NET for binding, it looks like you will need to put your JSON in the body of your request, and mark `DataSourceRequestModel req` with `[FromBody]`.  See [Why do I need FromBody Attribute when do a $http post with angularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34529346) and [Model binding JSON POSTs in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) and, maybe, [ASP.NET Core MVC Model Binding: Custom Binders](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1368/aspnet-core-mvc-custom-model-binding).