# StringContent results in null value but FormUrlEncodedContent works correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following model in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Which contains the following action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, false, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
            return new ObjectResult(await GenerateToken(user));
        }
    }
    return BadRequest(model);
}
```

When using StringContent with JsonConvert in a test client this results in NULL values showing up in the model when posted to the action on the controller.

```
var credentials = new LoginModel() { Username = "me@me.com", Password = "somePassword" };
var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");        
var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/auth/login", content);
```

When using FormUrlEncodedContent, the model is populated correctly in the action on the controller.

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "me@me.com"),
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "somePassword"),
}
var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/auth/login", content);
```

I've also tried using the HttpClient extensions which also results in no values showing up in the model when posted.

```
var credentials = new LoginModel() { Username = "me@me.com", Password = "somePassword" };
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<LoginModel>("/api/auth/login", credentials);
```

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need FromBody Attribute when expecting data in POST body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529346/why-do-i-need-frombody-attribute-when-expecting-data-in-post-body)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The answer might be the same but the question isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update action to look for the content in the request body using `[FromBody]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel model) {
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Reference [Asp.Net Core: Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)